# MMORPG - Representing Money in a DB table

Tags: mmo, databases

Where to begin... I'm currently busy with a few Udemy courses on game development using Unreal Engine 4. My end goal is to develop an MMORPG that I've always wanted to play, but never found online.

Q: How would I represent in-game money in a database table?

I've thought of adding it as a field in the "character" table, but then I struggle to see how I can implement it as a field in the "bank" table... Bank already has a quantity field, so I though about adding the money values as "items", but I just can't get myself to approve that...

Some information on the table fields:

- Each players bank will have a size limit (upgrade-able) on how many items they can place in it. I was thinking of moving it out to the "character" table as it doesn't really have anything to do with the bank table...

As for the rest of the tables, I'm still working on them. For now I just wanted to get the communities opinion on how to represent money in an mmorpg database.

[image: Current DB Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every player has one "cash money" value and one "bank money" value, so you could add both as integers values to the `character` table. If you really want to separate the banking system from the character system, you could create another table `bank_accounts` with the columns `character_id` and `money`.

Comment: Adding the field to the "character" table actually sounds like a good idea... Having everything character related including money in the same table. Thanks a lot for the quick response.